# Codename One BrowserComponent - read server certificate

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to read the server TLS certificate in the BrowserComponennt (specifically the public key)?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can probably use native interfaces to do that...

But I'm assuming that what you're trying to do is verify the server to protect against some attacks specifically through certificate pinning. Is that correct?

If so check out the certificate pinning section in the developer guide here; https://www.codenameone.com/manual/security.html

Comment: Thanks, I thougth that ;) We'll try to wrrite NA.

Comment: Concerning cert pinning - we use our authentication solution and want to add  public key to the authentication tvector o eliminate MITM attackers

Comment: What's missing from `checkSSLCertificates` and related APIs?  I don't follow? 
You can add a signature of the public certificate to verify it.

Comment: Certificate pinning checks only that cert chain is valid. If attacker has a valid certificate (and controls DNS - e.g. controls WiFi router) and redirects user to his site, pinníng won't help (cert is OK, domain is OK). Our authentication method uses public key for data channel binding to eliminate MITM attacker.

Comment: We don't have support for that at this time. You might be able to implement it using a cn1lib, e.g. before we built-in the pinning support we had this cn1lib: https://github.com/codenameone/SSLCertificateFingerprint it can serve as the basis for implementing what you want. Another option is that you can use a PR to add this feature to Codename One itself